# filter and compare two array in typescript with condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I filter some attributes with another `array` and if it match the condition, it will return another attributes, example :

```
Array1 = [{offenceCode: 'JLN14', offenceDesc:'Speeding'}]

Array2 = [{id:0, offenceCode: 'JLN14'}, {id:1, offenceCode: 'JLN13'}]
```

first I got `Array2` and compare the attribute `offenceCode` with `Array1`, and if it got same attribute, `Array1` should return `OffenceDesc`

this is what I had tried:

```
  demo = [
    {
      offenceCode: 'JLN14',
      offenceType: '7',
      offenceDesc: 'emergency lane abuse'
    },
    {
      offenceCode: 'BRG04',
      offenceType: '8',
      offenceDesc: 'speeding'
    },
    {
      offenceCode: 'CRG04',
      offenceType: '9',
      offenceDesc: 'emergency lane abuse'
    }
  ];

  offenceCode: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.offenceCode = this.items.map(x => x.offenceCode1);
    console.log(this.offenceCode);
    if(this.demo.forEach(x => x.offenceCode === this.offenceCode)) {
      // return offenceDesc
    }
  }
```

currently I got no idea how to solve this and this is my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpypya), I could use any suggestion on how to solve this and if there are better paractice, thanks

Comment: ++ Your stackblitz contains A LOT of files. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NicholasK sure, will updated my stackblitz

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda I just need to return offenceDesc if offenceCode same condition

Comment: Can you also throw in a couple more examples of the output you are expecting (with different input)?

Comment: I had minimal my stackblitz, @NicholasK

Comment: `offenceCode` exists only in demo - with what property of `items` do you want to compare it with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200127/discussion-between-hafizi-and-nicholas-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for:

```
offenceCode: string[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.offenceCode = this.items.map(x => x.offenceCode1);
  this.demo.forEach(x => {
    this.offenceCode
      .filter(e => e === x.offenceCode)
      .forEach(e => console.log(x.offenceDesc));
    });
}
```

Made the following edits:

1. You should define `offenceCode` as a string[]
2. Now you can loop over the `demo` array and preform a filter on *offenceCode* from the previous line. Any condition that is satisfied will now be logged to the console (you can change that as per your requirement)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to do this.

```
const matchIndex = this.demo.findIndex(x => x.offenceCode === this.offenceCode);
if(matchIndex !== -1) {
  return this.demo[matchIndex].offenceDesc;
}
return undefined;
```

Please note that the `findIndex` will return -1 if it didn't find a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit(){
  let Array1 = [{offenceCode: 'JLN14', offenceDesc:'Speeding'}]
  let Array2 = [{id:0, offenceCode: 'JLN14'}, {id:1, offenceCode: 'JLN13'}]

  let object = Array1.filter(x => x.offenceCode == Array2.filter(y => y.offenceCode == x.offenceCode)[0].offenceCode)[0]

  return object ? object.offenceDesc ? null
}
```