# filter array attributes typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I had 2 `array`:

```
  items = [
    {
      offenceType:"7",
      offenceCode:"JLN14",
    }, 
    {
      offenceType:"48",
      offenceCode:"JLN14",
    }
  ];



  demo = [
    {
      offenceCode: 'JLN14',
      offenceType: '7',
      offenceDesc: 'emergency lane abuse'
    },
    {
      offenceCode: 'JLN14',
      offenceType: '48',
      offenceDesc: 'speeding'
    },
    {
      offenceCode: 'JLN13',
      offenceType: '52',
      offenceDesc: 'parking abuse'
    }
  ];
```

How do I filter some attributes between this 2 `array` for example: 
in `items` got `offenceType` and `OffenceCode` so I need to compare it with `demo` which contains `offenceType`, `offenceCode` and `offenceDesc`, if both `offenceType` and `offenceCode`
are match, I need to get `offenceDesc` from `demo`, based on what I googled this is what I had tried:

```
  newArray = [];

  // create new array to map 2 objects
  this.items.forEach(x => {
    this.newArray.push(x.offenceCode, x.offenceType);
    console.log('newArray',this.newArray);
    // doing filter
  })
```

this is my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ciscap?file=src/app/demo/demo.component.ts)

previously I had ask question similar like this [prev question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157156/filter-and-compare-two-array-in-typescript-with-condition) but I couldnt figure it out eventhough had tried many times how to solve this problem,I am new to coding, hope anyone can give suggestion on how to solve this

Comment: This seems like essentially the same problem as your previous question, which you accepted an answer to. In what way does that not also solve this problem?

Comment: I couldnt figure on  how to solve this , if it is i need to map two objects or what

Comment: okay, sorry my mistakes,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map

```js
const items = [
  {
    offenceType:"7",
    offenceCode:"JLN14",
  }, 
  {
    offenceType:"48",
    offenceCode:"JLN14",
  }
];

const demo = [
  {
    offenceCode: 'JLN14',
    offenceType: '7',
    offenceDesc: 'emergency lane abuse'
  },
  {
    offenceCode: 'JLN14',
    offenceType: '48',
    offenceDesc: 'speeding'
  },
  {
    offenceCode: 'JLN13',
    offenceType: '52',
    offenceDesc: 'parking abuse'
  }
];

const newArray = items.map(item => {
   const lookup = demo.find(i => item.offenceType === i.offenceType);
   return {
     offenceType: lookup.offenceType,
     offenceCode: lookup.offenceCode,
     offenceDesc: lookup.offenceDesc
   }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function which finds the offense description and then use map on items with that function

```
const items = [
  {
    offenceType:"7",
    offenceCode:"JLN14",
  }, 
  {
    offenceType:"48",
    offenceCode:"JLN14",
  }
];

function findOffenseDesc(item) {
    const demo = [
        {
          offenceCode: 'JLN14',
          offenceType: '7',
          offenceDesc: 'emergency lane abuse'
        },
        {
          offenceCode: 'JLN14',
          offenceType: '48',
          offenceDesc: 'speeding'
        },
        {
          offenceCode: 'JLN13',
          offenceType: '52',
          offenceDesc: 'parking abuse'
        }
      ];
      const match = demo.find(offense => offense.offenceCode === item.offenceCode && offense.offenceType === item.offenceType);
      return match && match.offenceDesc;
}

const newArray = items.map(findOffenseDesc);
console.log(newArray); // [ "emergency lane abuse", "speeding" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter and map.  Assuming you just need offenceDesc

```
const offenceDescriptions = demo.filter(
    d => items.find(item => item.offenceCode === d.offenceCode
                         && item.offenceType === d.offenceType))
    .map(x => x.offenceDesc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negated logic with `every()` method.

Relevant code:

```
...

  newArray = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let  foundOffence: any;

    this.items.forEach(itemsOffence => {
      this.demo.every(demoOffence => {
        let isNoMatch: boolean = demoOffence.offenceCode != itemsOffence.offenceCode || demoOffence.offenceType != itemsOffence.offenceType;
        foundOffence = isNoMatch? undefined: demoOffence;
        return isNoMatch;
      })
      if (foundOffence) {
        console.log(`foundOffenceDesc = ${foundOffence.offenceDesc}`);
        this.newArray.push(foundOffence);
      }
    })
    console.log("newArray = ", this.newArray);
  }

...
```

You can see it working in this [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3tp6ex?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.ts)